# How to call a java exe file using powershell?

Tags: java, swing, powershell

I have created an application window using Java swing. I need to call my java exe file using powershell.. The Java application is done using java swing..I have exported the Java application to a jar file.. While double clicking the exe file i get the output executed.. My powershell code is this

```
$psi = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$psi.CreateNoWindow = $true $psi.UseShellExecute = $false
 $psi.FileName = 'java.exe' $psi.Arguments =
 @("-classpath","$Env:CLASSPATH","D:\")
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi) set-item -path Env:CLASSPATH
-value :\D:\ "CLASSPATH = $Env:CLASSPATH"  [Diagnostics.Process]::Start('java.exe','-classpath $Env:CLASSPATH
 D:\Swing.jar')
```

I am geeting a black window displayed and no errors.. My application program window is not displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need the `-jar` option to Java, as Sanjeev already noted.
2. Please don't write PowerShell as if it were some kind of C# with funky syntax. There is a `Start-Process` cmdlet, after all, if you really need it:

   ```
   Start-Process -FilePath java.exe -ArgumentList -jar,D:\Swing.jar,-classpath,$Env:CLASSPATH -NoNewWindow
   ```

   In this case you probably don't, so the following should work just as well (remember, PowerShell is a shell, hence the name; running programs is quite easy):

   ```
   java -jar D:\Swing.jar -classpath $Env:CLASSPATH
   ```

And if you don't want to have the console output, then use `javaw` instead of `java`. Control will return immediately to PowerShell, then, though.

Comment: I am creating a pop up window in java using swing. I need to pull details of a web site using powershell and display it in the popup window.. How could i do it?